# How to customize header in plupload

Tags: plupload

How can I customize the header with the colored plus logo in the left and the text 'Select files and Add files to the upload queue and click the start button.'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can customize the header by modifying the file "jquery.ui.plupload.js". This file will be available under the folder "js/jquery.ui.plupload".

You need to modify the following lines (line# 216, 217) in the js file.

```
'<div class="plupload_header_title">' + _("Select files") + '</div>' +
'<div class="plupload_header_text">' + _("Add files to the upload queue and click the start button.") + '</div>' +
```

You can also modify the css file (js/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css) to remove the + icon in the header.

I hope this helps!